# What is CloudPhotoLibraryErrorDomain Code = 27 ? (iCloud)

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

I'm trying to download data of phasset from iCloud using `PHImageManager.default().requestImageData`.

I receive an error which is

> CloudPhotoLibraryErrorDomainCode=27 Fetching resOriginalRes
>   (CPLResourceTypeOriginal) for X#PrimarySync succeeded but did not
>   return the resource

Could anyone help me how I can fix the error? What is the cause to trigger the error?